# BI Publisher- RTF Template - PDF secured with Employee's SSN number?

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps

I am new to **BI publisher** and previously totally working on SQL coding for fetching everything but now i have installed BI Publisher extension for Word Document. I have a requirement through which all the PDF's gets generated at the time of Bursting, it should go protected with a password. And the bursting for those PDF's are basis on employee Number, i.e. separate letter for every employee, now i have to protect employee wise generated PDF with employee's SSN number.

The documents which i am using as a reference are:

[Reference One](https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/secure-your-pdfs)

[Reference Two](https://www.howtogeek.com/217329/how-to-create-custom-properties-in-a-word-document/).

Point of confusion for me is, how to add a custom value parameter which supports the Password, steps to make my RTF password protected, code to validate the password.

```
    Thanks in Advance!!
```

Answer (score 0):

For this data set:

```
<data>
<set1>
<row>
<attribute1>A</attribute1>
<attribute2>A1</attribute2>
<attribute3>A11</attribute3>
</row>
<row>
<attribute1>B</attribute1>
<attribute2>B1</attribute2>
<attribute3>B11</attribute3>
</row>
<row>
<attribute1>C</attribute1>
<attribute2>C1</attribute2>
<attribute3>C11</attribute3>
</row>
</set1>
</data>
```

Attribute1 being what you want to set the password to.

Your RTF file should have properties 
(Word -> File -> Info -> Properties -> Advanced Properties):

```
Name: xdo-pdf-open-password  Value: {data/set1/row/attribute1}
Name: xdo-pdf-security       Value: true
```